# Approximate solution of nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation-theory

Investigating some problem in optics I am faced with a nonlinear differential equation of the form
$$ - y(x)\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{x^2}}}\left( {\frac{1}{{y(x)}}} \right) + {y^2}(x) = f(x)$$
with initial conditions $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = \varepsilon $ where $\varepsilon  > 0$ is a small parameter and ${f(x)}$ is  a function for which we can analytically solve (explicitly provide two independent solutions) of the linear equation $p''(x) + f(x)p(x) = 0$.

It can be seen that (because $y(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$) $\frac{1}{{y(x)}}$ should satisfy in the limit $x \to 0$
$$\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{x^2}}}\left( {\frac{1}{{y(x)}}} \right) + \frac{{f(x)}}{{y(x)}} = 0$$
and we know a solution of this equation, but the first problem arises here. In some cases, it is not uniquely determined by the initial conditions. For example, if $f(x) = 1 - 2{x^{ - 2}}$ we get
$$y(x) \to \frac{{\varepsilon x}}{{\left( {1 + Cx} \right)\cos x + \left( {x - C} \right)\sin x}}$$
as $x \to 0$ so I don't even understand how to solve it numerically.

I tried to use this asymptotic ${y_0}(x)$ to get
$$\frac{{{d^2}\psi }}{{d{x^2}}} + f(x)\psi  = \frac{1}{{{y_0}(x) + \psi (x)}}$$
with $\psi (0) = \psi '(0) = 0$ but failed to find any good solutions using an expansion $\psi  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{ + \infty } {{\psi _k}{\varepsilon ^k}} $ (in the first order they seem to have a singularity).

So I didn't expect this to have any exact/explicit solutions but tried to find that it is possible to find a "wide-range" asymptotic using a small parameter $\varepsilon $ or just even solve it numerically -- I try to use ${y_0}(x)$ to "shift" the initial conditions from 0 to some small number, but the numerical solution from that point has a singularity that strongly depends on the initial point. I don't have much experience with nonlinear ODEs, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you get the solution involving the constant $C$?

Comment: Beacuse $y(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ in this limit $y(x)$ should go to the solution of
$$ - \frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{x^2}}}\left( {\frac{1}{{y(x)}}} \right) = \frac{{f(x)}}{{y(x)}}$$
The solution
$$y(x) \to \frac{{\varepsilon x}}{{\left( {1 + Cx} \right)\cos x + \left( {x - C} \right)\sin x}}$$
is the solution of the equation above that satisfy $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = \varepsilon $

Comment: How was that solution *derived*, is what I mean

Comment: Ok. Using substitution $y(x) = {\varphi ^{ - 1}}(x)$ we get that in limit $x \to 0$ $\varphi (x)$ is the solution of the equation
$$\frac{{{d^2}\varphi }}{{d{x^2}}} + f(x)\varphi (x) = 0$$
If $f(x) = 1 - 2{x^{ - 2}}$ it's a well-known equation that can be "reduced" to the Bessel equation. The general solution is
$$\varphi (x) = {C_1}\left( {\frac{{\sin x}}{x} - \cos x} \right) + {C_2}\left( {\frac{{\sin x}}{x} + \cos x} \right)$$
Now we get back to $y(x)$ and use initial conditions, that can be fullfilled with only chosing one constant.

Comment: Of course, but it is a solution in limit $x(t) \to 0$, not the solution of the initial equation in the whole $[0, + \infty )$